# Using Bayes for combining forecasts with different accuracies (Interview question)

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian, bayes-theorem

> I have 3 independent sources for tomorrow's weather forecast:
>
> 1. 100% probability for snow, this source is 80% accurate
> 2. 50% probability for snow, this source is 60% accurate
> 3. 0% probability for snow, this source is 40% accurate
>
> The accuracy for each source is:
>   $$\frac{\text{Number of correct forecasts}}{\text{Total number of forecasts}}$$ 
>   What is the best estimate for the probability for snow tomorrow?

Essentially it is an extension of a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155817/combining-probabilities-information-from-different-sources/), but where each source has a different accuracy or reliability.

Also, the selected answer suggested using the geometric mean, ignoring the fact that one of the probabilities is 0, collapsing the entire answer to 0 which intuitively makes no sense: the forecast with the lowest accuracy should not supersede a more accurate forecast just because of numerical considerations.

My intuition was to solve it weighing probabilities with accuracies:
$$(1 *0.8 + 0.5 * 0.6 + 0 * 0.4) / (0.8 + 0.6 + 0.4)$$
but the interviewer insisted on solving using Bayes theorem.

In addition, if one of my sources has accuracy 100%, then it makes no sense to calculate a weighed mean with the other sources.

I could weigh as in [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost#Weighting):
$$\alpha_m = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left( \frac{1 - \epsilon_m}{\epsilon_m}\right)$$
so e.g. for the source with accuracy 80%, the weight would be
$$\alpha_m = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left( \frac{0.8}{0.2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(4)$$
etc. Is this an acceptable solution for this question?
In any case I'd be very happy to see how it can be solved using Bayes.

I have seen a [few](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374585/weather-station-brain-teaser/) [other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251635/combining-forecasts-for-discrete-outcomes) [questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33104/combining-different-accuracies) [similar](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219107/is-it-possible-to-add-up-the-accuracy-rates-of-2-predictors) to it, but none exactly the same.

Comment: @heropup Hope I've corrected the question as required. Is it enough to take me out of hold?